# show message if search item did not found using ng-multiselect-dropdown Search filter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown for the search filter...
I would like to show 'No items Matches' message if the searched item is not available in the dropdown List...

**Angular component**

````
  this.getDynamicFilterList();
  this.settings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'tag_id',
    textField: 'tag_name',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: true,
    clearSearchFilter: true,
  };
}

getDynamicFilterList() {
  this.filterService.getDynamicFilter().subscribe(res => {
    let dummyArr = [];
    for (let key in res.data) {
      dummyArr.push(res.data[key])
    }
    let group = {}
    this.filterDynamicDropdown = dummyArr;
    this.filterDynamicDropdown.forEach(dynamic_filter => {
      group[dynamic_filter.category_id] = new FormControl('');
    })
    this.dynamicFormGroup = new FormGroup(group);
  })
}```

***Angular Template***
```<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup" *ngIf="dynamicFormGroup">
<div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let item of filterDynamicDropdown">
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown class="dynamic-dropdown" placeholder="{{item.category_name}}" [settings]="settings"
    [data]="item.value" [disabled]="false" (onFilterChange)="onFilterChange($event,item.value)"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onDeSelect)="onDeSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)" formControlName="{{item.category_id}}">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
</form>```
````

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Track pull request [here](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/pull/322)

**OLD**

Try adding 'noDataAvailablePlaceholderText' property to this.settings as follows:

```
this.settings = {
   singleSelection: false,
   idField: 'tag_id',
   textField: 'tag_name',
   selectAllText: 'Select All',
   unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
   itemsShowLimit: 3,
   allowSearchFilter: true,
   clearSearchFilter: true,
   noDataAvailablePlaceholderText: 'No items Matches'
};
```

Comment: noDataAvailablePlaceholderText  does work when dropdown list is empty. But i want this message while searching invalid item while filtering from list

Comment: Turns out this is a long-standing issue on ng-multiselect-dropdown. Have added a pull request with fixes. Can track [here](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/pull/322)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "noFilteredDataAvailablePlaceholderText:'your message' " like:

```
  this.settings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'tag_id',
    textField: 'tag_name',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: true,
    clearSearchFilter: true,
noFilteredDataAvailablePlaceholderText:'message you want to show'
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.